# How to Remove element when reaches screen edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, 2d-games

I am using jquery to make a simple shooting game from the left side of screen to the right. When the bullet is shot it will travel forever to the right. How can i remove it when it reaches a certain coordinate at the end of the page?

This makes the bullet move...

```
var flyingBullet = function(){

      $(".bullet").each(function() {
            var oldLeft = $(this).offset().left;
            $(this).css("left", oldLeft + 10 + "px");
        });
}

setInterval(flyingBullet, 200);
```

Comment: This question shows no research effort.

Comment: 1) use a var to hold the result of setInterval to be able to do a clearInterval 2) remove it when left>= $(window).width

Answer (score 0):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/lizilo/1/)**

(Use jQuery's `.remove()` method once the bullet is at *`leftPosition === worldWidth`*).

---

<sup>(I would do that all in **Canvas**, for better **performance** results, visuals and repainting, but here you go: )</sup>

I find a really **bad idea** to loop constantly **uncached** `$()` class selector elements.

Create among other variables like...

```
var world = {$el:$("body"), width: $('body').width()};
var $player = $('#player');
var mousePosY = 0;
```

...an Array that will **hold all the created Bullets**

```
var allBullets = [];
```

to keep track of all the active bullets and to **remove** them.

Than **create a Bullet Object** with the bullet properties (with inner handlers for the position, color, shape, speed etc etc...) and append that Object to our Array of bullets and insert it into the DOM:

```
function Bullet() {
  var obj = {
    $el : $('<div/>',{'class':'bullet'}),
    css : {top: 100, left:0},   // Start at left 0
    speed : 10,
    move : function() { // This method will be used inside the animation loop!
      obj.css.left += obj.speed;      // Advance Bullet
      if(obj.css.left > world.width){ // Notice this!!!!
        var i = allBullets.indexOf(obj); // !! Use of indexOf (xBr. support).
        allBullets.splice(i, 1);
        obj.$el.remove();
      }else{
        return obj.$el.css( obj.css );
      }
    }
  };
  allBullets.push( obj );
  $('body').prepend( obj.$el );
  return obj;      
}
```

To **remove** the bullets (as you can see in the **code above**) simply:

```
var i = allBullets.indexOf(obj); // Find the index of that object inside Array
allBullets.splice(i, 1); // Remove it from Array
obj.$el.remove();        // Remove it from the DOM
```

Note that [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) is introduced in ES5 and not present in old browsers. You might want to use a [Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) or replace it with an object that will collect Bullets ID... (I'll not cover that topic in this answer).

Once the player clicks to "Fire" you simply create a `new` instance of that Bullet like:

```
$("body").on('click', function(){
  new Bullet(); // Create a new Bullet with all the properties, move etc.
});
```

and it will be immediately collected into the `allBullets` Array.

To move the bullets you pass the the window.requestAnimationFrame :

```
function moveBullets(){
  if(allBullets.length>0) // Only if we have bullets in Array!
  for(var i=0; i<allBullets.length; i++) allBullets[i].move(); // Move it using
                                                               // his own method.
}
```

I don't see how's that bullet supposed to **fly nicely**? 20 by 20px every 200ms?
Also for animation purposes I would go with [`window.requestAnimationFrame`](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame.html) instead of `setInterval`, to allow the browser dictate the repainting tempo.

```
// ::: FRAME RATE
window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {
  return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function( callback ){
      window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
}());

// ::: ENGINE
(function engine() {
  // ----- Insert here functions you want to loop in framerate:
  moveBullets();
  // -----
  requestAnimFrame(engine); // request a new frame
})();
```

If you really want to use DOM element, I would also suggest to use **enhanced CSS3 transitions** and move the element with `translate3d(x, y, z)`. You'll not have to move the element every tick, but the browser will move it for you! You can pre-calculate it trajectory in order to keep track of the element position in relation to the animation framerate and an internal clock. (I'll also not cover this examples in my answer.)

The above was for guidance, take a look at the result
**[in this DEMO (with random bullets speed)](http://jsbin.com/lizilo/1/)**